# How to pass a javascript array to ASP.NET MVC model?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a field object in ASP.NET MVC and store it to a database. The field should contain its coordinates which the user can select with the google maps api.
And now, how can I pass the coordinates of the markers, which are stored in a javascript array, to the Model´s List?

This is my Controller for this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BL;
using MvcAgrarTest.Models;

namespace MvcAgrarTest.Controllers
{
    public class FieldsController : Controller
    {
        private MvcAgrarContext db = new MvcAgrarContext();

        // GET: Fields
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var field = db.CreateFieldViewModel.Include(f => f.FieldType);
            return View(field.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Fields/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new CreateFieldViewModel();
            ViewBag.FieldTypeId = new SelectList(db.FieldType, "FieldTypeId", "Name");
            return View(model);
        }

        // POST: Fields/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateFieldViewModel model, CreateFieldViewModel field, string[] markers)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                PostCoordinates(markers);
                db.CreateFieldViewModel.Add(field);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.FieldTypeId = new SelectList(db.FieldType, "FieldTypeId", "Name", field.FieldTypeId);
            return Json(true);
        }     
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


    }
}
```

Here my Create View with the Google Maps script:

```
@model MvcAgrarTest.Models.CreateFieldViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Feld anlegen</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "Feldname", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FieldTypeId, "Feldtyp", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("FieldTypeId", null, "--Feldart auswählen--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FieldTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Size, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Size, new { htmlAttributes = new { @placeholder = "In Hektar", @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Size, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>  
        </div>           
            <div id="google">
                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                var map;

                function initialize() {
                    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.617109, 8.065738);
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 5,
                        center: myLatLng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                    // array to store markers that has been drawn
                    var markers = [];

                    //  event listener draw a marker
                    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker();

                        marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
                        marker.setMap(map);
                        marker.setVisible(true);

                        markers.push(marker);

                        // draw polygon on marker click
                        // once user clicks on on of the markers 
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (e) {
                            document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "";
                            drawPoints(markers);
                            label.style.borderStyle = "dotted"
                            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
                                document.getElementById("label").innerHTML += markers[i].position;

                            }

                            // empty the markers array 
                            markers = [];
                        });

                    });

                }

                function drawPoints(markers) {
                    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon;

                    var points = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        points.push(markers[i].getPosition());
                    }
                    poly.setMap(map);
                    poly.setPath(points);
                    poly.setVisible(true);
                }
            </script>
            <body onload="initialize()">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
            </body>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Erstellen" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>       

}
```

and finally my ViewModel to create the field:

```
public class CreateFieldViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name="ID")]
        public int FieldId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Fieldname")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name="Fieldtype")]
        public int FieldTypeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0.01, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The Size can´t be 0 or less")]
        [Display(Name="Fieldsize")]
        public float Size { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Coordinates")]
        public List<string> Coordinates { get; set; }

        public virtual FieldType FieldType { get; set; }        
    }
```

**/edit: Id did it like this now, but it still doesn´t work**

changed part from the google maps API:

```
var passdata = [];
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e){
    for (y=0; y<markers.length; ++y){
        passdata[y] = markers[y].position
    }
    drawpoints(markers);
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Create","Fields")",
        typ: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({coordinates: passdata}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
    });
```

And the Controller Function:

```
// GET: Fields/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var model = new CreateFieldViewModel();
            ViewBag.FieldTypeId = new SelectList(db.FieldType, "FieldTypeId", "Name");
            return View(model);
        }

// POST: Fields/Create           
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(CreateFieldViewModel field, string[] coordinates)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        field.Coordinates = coordinates;
        db.CreateFieldViewModel.Add(field);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.FieldTypeId = new SelectList(db.FieldType, "FieldTypeId", "Name", field.FieldTypeId);
    return View(field);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 `CreateFieldViewModel` parameters in the POST method (is that a typo?). Are you referring to the values you add to `var markers = [];`?

Comment: The two ViewModels are just a mistake by myself..

Answer (score 2):

I understood, (looking by you code) that you want to go with submitting form, and not ajax?

If so, you have two choices (known to me):

1. Create html hidden input and paste there as value serialized JSON of your markers array - but you will have to deserialize this value later. In this example you need to change Coordinates type in your model to string.

JavaScript

```
// some sample coordinates, you need to extract them from markers
var coordinates = ["12,21","213,231"]; 
var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(coordinates);
$("#coordinatesInput").val(dataToSend);
```

HTML

```
<input hidden id="coordinatesInput" name="model.Coordinates" value=""/>
```

2. Create dynamically, using JavaScript (for example append function) many hidden html inputs with name model.Coordinates[i] and value of single coordinate (use some loop).

JavaScript

```
var coordinates = ["231,2132","312,231","231,321"];

var container = $("#container");
//container, where you will be adding inputs, in you example it could be form-horizontal class
coordinates.forEach(function(val, i){
  container.append('<input hidden name="model.Coordinates['+i+']" value="'+val+'">');
});
```

Of course using AJAX is much better way, and AlexB answer is way to go, but mechanism of it is a little different. It is good to use only AJAX (not form submitting), because in your example you need to use two Actions, one for AJAX and one for form submitting.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your Javascript array to your controller using an Ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
        url         :    "@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")",
        contentType :    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType    :    "json",
        type        :    "POST",
        data        :    JSON.stringify({coordinates: markers})
 })
```

(where *markers* is your JS array to pass to the controller, I guess)

And your controller will look like

```
public ActionResult MethodName(Single[] coordinates)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: When I run it in Debug Mode with an Breakpoint at the Createbutton, Visual Studio shows me that the coordinates array just contains one item with the value 0.

Comment: What is the content of your JS array just before sending it to the ajax call ?

Comment: Just before the ajax call, the array contains a list of marker- objects (amount depents on how many markers have been set). The coordinates can be accessed with markers[i].position and these coordinates  I want to save in the Model´s coordinates list.

Comment: You don't have to pass a list of markers to your controller, but only the lat/lng of each markers. Create a new JS array based on your actual array, and fill it in a `for` loop via `marker[i].lat()` and `marker[i].lng`. Then pass this new array (containing only lat/lng of your markers) to your controller. I don't know if it is the cleanest way to do, but this works for me, reduces the amount of bandwith used, and have better performances for large arrays.

Comment: `.position` returns an object containing the lat and the lng, whereas in my sample, `MethodName` waits for a simple `Single[]`, which is an array of single, and not an array of object. If you want to use a `Single[]` in your controller, you have to fill `passdata` with `markers[y].position.lat()` and `.lng()`. Or use a more complex type in your controller, but I'm unsure how to do it.